# Copy value into consts for optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, variables, optimization, constants

Assume that your first objective is execution speed, then code cleanliness and finally usage of resources.

If at a certain point of an algorithm a variable (for instance a double) is not going to change any more (but you are still going to read it many times), would you copy it into a constant value?

Comment: Chances are high that the compiler will detect that your variable isn't going to be changed anymore and optimize things out (if they can be) as a result of this observation. Now if it makes the code clearer, go ahead. But you probably shouldn't worry too much about such "optimizations".

Comment: I think, Herb Sutter describes exactly this problem here: [Complex initialization for a const variable](http://herbsutter.com/2013/04/05/complex-initialization-for-a-const-variable/).

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: That's a good tip. Why don't you make it an answer ? I would be happy to upvote that.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: Even without lambda, I have often enough used a `static` function to do the initialization... and note that I see no claim about performance in Sutter's post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make your code clearer, by all means, copy your values into a `const double const_value = calculated_value;`, but compilers are very good at tracking dependencies, and it's highly unlikely (assuming you are using a modern, reasonably competent compiler) that the code will be any faster or otherwise "better" because you do this. There is a small chance that the compiler takes your word for the fact that you want a second variable, and thus makes a copy, and makes the code slower because of that.

As always, if performance is important to your application, make a "before & after" comparative benchmark for your particular code, as reading a page on the internet or asking on SO is not the same as benchmarking your code.

Answer (score 3):

Just copying non-constant variable into a constant one does not make the code cleaner because instead of one variable you have two. Much more interesting would be to move non-constant one out-of-scope. This way, we have only constant version of the variable visible and compiler prevents us from changing its value by mistake.

Herb Sutter describes how to do this using C++11 lambdas: [Complex initialization for a const variable](http://herbsutter.com/2013/04/05/complex-initialization-for-a-const-variable/).

```
const int i = [&]{
  int i = some_default_value;

  if(someConditionIstrue)
  {
    Do some operations and calculate the value of i;
    i = some calculated value;
  }

  return i;
} ();
```

(I don't explain execution speed objective since it is already done by Mats Petersson).

Comment: Personally I hope that this idiom does’t become established, it’s garbage. Give the lambda a name, then we’re talking.

Comment: I think Mats Petersson answer is better related to the question, but this usage of lambda is nice, unfortunately a bit inflexible too: imagine that the operations bring straightforwardly also to a second initialization value j (for another variable, let's say we are computing a sincos), you won't be able to return it for assignation.

Comment: @DarioP: to initialize a second/third... variable this lambda could return a pair, a tuple, or a structure. But this would be much less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

For better code readability, you can create a const reference to the variable at the point where it isn't changed anymore, and use the const reference from that point on.

```
double value_init;
// Some code that generates value_init...
const double& value = value_init;
// Use value from now on in your algorithm
```